# How to inserting a custom view in XML in Android

Tags: android, android-xml, android-custom-view

I have a **class A** that extends class `View`.

I have a **class B** that extends **class A**.

Now I'm trying to add **class B** into my xml however I'm unable to do that whereas I'm able to add **class A** into my xml.

One more thing which I've noticed is that all other custom classes which directly extends `View` are visible inside my xml.

I wanna know whether is there any way of adding a class which extends another class which in turn extends `View`  into my xml?

NOTE : I'm using proper xml format and complete package name.

**CLASS A**

```
public class A extends View implements Serializable{

    public A(final Context context, final AttributeSet attrs,
            final int defStyle, final SomeEnum myType) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    }

    public A(final Context context, final AttributeSet attrs,
            final SomeEnum myType) {
        this(context, attrs, 0, testStateType);
    }

    public A(final Context context,
            final SomeEnum myType) {
        this(context, null, 0, testStateType);
    }

    public A(final Context context,
            final AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onSizeChanged(final int w, final int h, final int oldw,
            final int oldh) {
        invalidate();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onMeasure(final int widthMeasureSpec,
            final int heightMeasureSpec) {
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {

    }
}
```

**CLASS B**

```
public class B extends A
{
    public B(final Context context,
            final AttributeSet attrs, final int defStyle, final SomeEnum myType)
    {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle, testStateType);
    }

    public B(final Context context, final AttributeSet attrs, final SomeEnum myType)
    {
        this(context, attrs, 0, testStateType);
    }

    public B(final Context context, final SomeEnum myType)
    {
        this(context, null, 0, testStateType);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas)
    {
        super.onDraw(canvas);
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean "I'm unable to add"? Something doesn't allow you to do it?

Comment: There shouldn't be any problems doing that. You need to post the XML

Comment: To add a custom view in xml you need to use it's full package name like `<com.myproj.myview.CustomElement ...\>`

Comment: @AndroidWarrior i don't think Ctrl+Space is going to show your custom views i think it only shows android's default.

Comment: @AndroidWarrior It doesn't mean anything. Did you try to type and compile?

Comment: @AndroidWarrior - This is because your xml is wrong. Post it or revise it.

Comment: @AndroidWarrior i just made a similar scenario as you described and the de xml recognized the A class but not the B class but i added it anyway and the compiler accepts it, and works fine.

Comment: @HugoAlves There is no issues at comile time but at run time i'm getting 

**android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #9: Error inflating class com.test.SubclassOfView**

Comment: @AndroidWarrior check the call stack. You may be missing one of the required constructors, or the constructor is throwing an exception.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

class B is missing the constructor with the default arguments. Add:

```
public B(final Context context, final AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
}
```

to your class and you will be able to inflate it from an XML with your other views.

In general, adding custom parameters to a View's constructors is not a good practice. Use a custom attribute for that.

Answer (score 1):

Custom views must have the following constructors:

```
public CustomView(Context context)
{
    super(context);
}

public CustomView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs)
{
    super(context, attrs);
}

public CustomView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle)
{
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);
}
```

Looks like you only have overloads that receive a `SomeEnum` parameter, but the `LayoutInflater` doesn't know how to call those.

Comment: Very close to the answer mate but `SomeEnum` parameter isn't causing any problem. Although it's not a good practice though as @ivagarz said. +1 for the explanation.

Comment: That's exactly what I meant...  You can have extra constructors, but the others are required. You only had the ones receiving SomeEnum.

Answer (score 0):

**Why you getting android inflating exception error ?**

Mostly it is caused for xml error. If you are trying to set a properties of a view by illegal resources , layouts etc, your program will crash as your brain. For an example: You can not set a textView background by an layout xml file, you know that very well. But it may happens when you getting fast and using eclipse suggestions. Looking at logcat you can see  ” Binary XML file line 20 or something” . Its telling you at which line the error is.

**Caused by:**

`android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #9: Error inflating class`

**Solution:**

This tells that the class name you defined is not found. Check the class name carefully or check the build path.
If one of this resources has a high pixel resolution it would take a lot of memory causing then an inflate exception.

For more common android InflateExceptions: [Android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line # xx](http://androidexception.com/android-solutions/android-view-inflateexception-binary-xml-file-line-xx.html).

Comment: Just try the above classes that as they are i.e. without the constructor mentioned by @ivagarz. Use the complete qualified name of your class in your xml and try inflating it in your `getView()`. You won't receive a `ComileTimeException` but a `RunTimeException` i.e. `android.view.InflateException`.