# How to add CustomView to layout

Tags: java, android, xml, layout

I know that there are lot of questions about "How to add CustomView to Layout" but I read almost all and i have still problem.
CustomView in XML

```
<slccs.drawingapplication.DrawLine
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/drawline"/>
```

And Java code of this View

`package slccs.drawingapplication;
 import android.content.Context;
 import android.view.View;`

```
public class DrawLine extends View {

public DrawLine(Context c){
    super(c);
}}
```

I am getting this error `The following classes could not be found:- slccs.drawingapplication.DrawLine`

When I Clean project I will get more errors:

`Error:Error: Invalid file name: must contain only lowercase letters and digits ([a-z0-9_.])` it is about my `@drawable/Brown` Image file. So When I change `B` to `b`    I`ll get new problem in activity_main xml file:

`Couldn't resolve resource @drawable/brown`

`Failed to convert @drawable/brown into a drawable`

I think that Today is AndroidStudio hating me :(

I don`t know where is the problem

Thank you for your answers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found this tidbit [here](https://developer.android.com/training/custom-views/create-view.html).

> To allow the Android Developer Tools to interact with your view, ***at a
>   minimum*** you must provide a constructor that takes a ***Context and an***
>   **AttributeSet** object as parameters. This constructor allows the layout
>   editor to create and edit an instance of your view.

and it seems that part of your issue is covered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24265081/how-to-inserting-a-custom-view-in-xml-in-android).

As for the `@drawable/brown` I'm guessing it is either incompatible with the system, or you messed up in the file you created it in.  But since I don't know what the drawable is (hint hint, code for that please!), I can't really tell you exactly why it won't compile, but yes, you do NEED to have all lowercase letters when naming it, so `brown.yourfiletype` is correct.

Try restarting Android Studio.

Comment: AttributeSet was one of the things that caused error, I had to `rebuild project` and then worked fine.                                                                            For the `@drawable/brown`  Restarting AndroidStudio worked.

Answer (score 2):

```
public class DrawLine extends View {

public DrawLine(Context c){
    super(c);
}

public DrawLine(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(c);
}
}
```

Comment: Sorry, this didn`t helped me.

Comment: you must implement the other constructor as in the posted example , while accesssing the view from xml you need the constructor with attributeSet

Comment: also you  cannot have Uppercase file name for files in resource folder , follow the naming convention

Answer (score 0):

First Declaring this custom view in your layout :

```
 <slccs.drawingapplication.DrawLine
```

mean you have a class DrawLine located in the package : 
"slccs.drawingapplication"

Second , android expect file name to start with  lowercase and contain only alphanumerical char and '-' or '.'.

so be sure you ve copied  brown picture in your drawable folder and tell us if all is ok now